# Recursive md5sum differs on windows and linux

Tags: linux, cygwin, md5sum

I'm doing this on both Windows (with cygwin) and a Linux box:

```
find DWH-R1.4.3/ -type f -print0 | sort -z | xargs -r0 md5sum | md5sum
```

in order to get a consistent md5sum for a software-delivery. But I get different md5sums on each machine.

I thought it could be because of newline-stuff, but since I transferred the whole directory as a zip file binary, this seems not the case. I even tried dos2unix after the first md5sum, it did not change the sum.
Any ideas how I can use md5sum consistently in this case?

Thanks and regards

Chris

Comment: The systems could have different locales set so the sort is different, or md5sum could output blanks on one system  and tabs on the other. If you save the 2 lists of files and sums into files and run diff on them, what does it show?

Comment: Yeah thanks, sorry I did not see, that on cygwin it puts a '*' in front of the filename:
    272a1f8c702f33ec5ae15b36b679e7a9 *DWH-R1.4.3/RELEASENOTES

and
 
    272a1f8c702f33ec5ae15b36b679e7a9  DWH-R1.4.3/RELEASENOTES
 are different in the end-md5sum-computing of course ;-) I still have to find out, why this happens on windows, but first try to strip out the *

Answer (score 0):

OK, I sorted it out now: Linux and Windows (cygwin) versions of sort are sorting different: the "." comes before letters on the linux versions (which imho is wrong if we look at the ASCII table). I solved it by not using the filenames, I'm interested in the md5sum only anyway:

```
find DWH-R1.4.3/ -type f -print0 | xargs -r0 md5sum | awk '{ print $1 }' | sort | md5sum
```

seems to work out well :-)

BTW: I used the same LOCALE settings on both.